# Altering mysql database column causes error in another column

Tags: mysql, alter-table

First of all sorry everybody if this question sounds too basic.

I have a Wordpress database and a table `wp_comments`.

In this table, I have two `DATETIME` fields, whose default value is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

I need to change this value to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, so for example I run the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_comments` MODIFY `comment_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

So, `comment_date` (NOT `comment_date_gmt`) is the column to modify.

Now, when I run this query I get the following error:

```
Error 1067: Invalid default value for comment_date_gmt
```

Why is this happening? What could I do?

[UPDATE]

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_comments` (
  `comment_ID` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `comment_post_ID` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_author` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `comment_author_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_author_url` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_author_IP` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `comment_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `comment_content` text NOT NULL,
  `comment_karma` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment_approved` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `comment_agent` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'comment',
  `comment_parent` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `wp_comments`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`comment_ID`),
  ADD KEY `comment_post_ID` (`comment_post_ID`),
  ADD KEY `comment_approved_date_gmt` (`comment_approved`,`comment_date_gmt`),
  ADD KEY `comment_date_gmt` (`comment_date_gmt`),
  ADD KEY `comment_parent` (`comment_parent`),
  ADD KEY `comment_author_email` (`comment_author_email`(10));
```

MySQL version is 5.7.33

[UPDATE]

I don't know WHY but I know HOW I solved this issue:

```
ALTER TABLE `wp_comments` MODIFY `comment_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, MODIFY `comment_date_gmt` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

This way, by modifying **both fields together**, I get no errors.

It works, but I'm still quite curious, so if have any idea to share...   :-)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! Please include the output (as text) of the command `SHOW CREATE TABLE wp_comments\G`! Use the edit link under the question!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community: I need to change the default datetime column value from 0000-00-00 00:00:00 to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP: I'm NOT talking about data stored, but field structure, instead. Sorry if my question wasn't clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) says, for the `DATETIME` data type

> supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'

Presumably your table was created while the [`NO_ZERO_DATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_zero_date) mode was *not* in effect, which allowed the `0000-00-00` date part, but it seems to be in effect now, thus, along with the strict mode, producing the error you see. When you modify `comment_date`, other column definitions are also revalidated according to the current SQL mode, and revalidation of the `comment_date_gmt` fails.

Comment: Yes, the tables were created some years ago, you're right. And the NO_ZERO_DATE is currently "in effect". Thank you very much